# Speech translation

Tags: translation, speech

I wan to integrate the Speech to text api  and translator api ? Am looking to integrate both the api to get speech as Input and speech as output. Can anyone guide on the Issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use SpeechRecognizer Class for it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.aspx

Comment: is that complete ? am looking for advance one